# After Joomla! upgrade, the error JLIB_APPLICATION_ERROR_APPLICATION_LOAD shows

Tags: joomla, updates

I have experimented with and debugged this issue for a couple of hours. After updating Joomla to 3.2.7 (copy-paste .zip file contents or the "one-click" method), the message

> Error displaying the error page: Application Instantiation Error. JLIB_APPLICATION_ERROR_APPLICATION_LOAD

shows up.

Debugging showed me that the class JApplicationInstaller is about to be loaded, can't be found anywhere, and that is what crashes Joomla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the /installation directory was still present in the application root. This directory should have been deleted after Joomla was installed by the user, but this step had been missed during the original installation of the website.

Restore your website from a backup, delete this directory and execute your update again, and it should work.

Comment: @Elin not yet, in another 23 hours I can.

Answer (score 0):

When you are manually updating Joomla you need to be careful as you have to follow certain steps after overwriting the files.

1. First you need to fix the database as the tables are now changed and overwriting files will not update database. For that you need to go to administrator and then you have to go to Extensions->manage->Database and then click on Fix Database. That will update your database too.
2. Next you have to install the extensions that came with new Joomla version. These are not yet updated in #__assets table. SO you go to Extensions->manage->Discover and then click on Discover. When it discovers new extensions just install the core Joomla extensions.

Comment: I did not know that about discovering new Joomla extensions, thank you. The problem I had though was the /installation directory still being present - I answered my own question.